# Match range of numbers like 10..15A..20

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have values in my db as follows

```
1 
2 
2A 
.......
10
10A
.......
250A
......
300
```

and i need to find the records that are within range 1-10,11-20,....291-300

can't figure out how to do this as there are characters after number

I'm using postgres db so i can apply regex query on db

Comment: Why not normalize your data and have a field that *just* has numbers in?

Comment: every number is a law section has unique meaning so cannot normalize it

Comment: @NEO-xx you could easily normalize that to something like `section = 250 AND subsection = 'A'` (where `subsection` is nullable)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
SUBSTRING(mycolumn FROM '^[0-9]+')
```

in order to extract the number that is at the start of your column.

To perform the filtering you want, you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(mycolumn FROM '^[0-9]+') AS INT) BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/be0ff8/5)